# How to download all files in folder Google drive api to Spring boot with StreamingResponseBody response Angular client download zip file?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-drive-api, zip

I have to download all file in a folder in google drive api. As I know google drive api not support download all. So the solution for this is get all file in folder and download file by file. I have done download a specific file but I got trouble when download all file in folder and zip it in angular. The result file cannot extract.
Currently in my backend spring boot:
resoure:

```
@GetMapping("/download-folder/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> download(@PathVariable String id) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(googleDriveService.downloadFolder(id));
}
```

Service

```
    public StreamingResponseBody downloadFolder(String id) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Drive drive = getService();
        List<File> files = getAllFilesInFolder(id);

        StreamingResponseBody stream = output -> {
            files.forEach(file -> {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try {
                    drive.files().get(file.getId()).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(baos);
                    output.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    output.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error when download file in folder ", e);
                }
            });
        };

        return stream;
    }
```

In front-end Angular:

```
  downloadFolder(id: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/download-folder/${id}`, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

Component:

```
  downloadFolder(): void {
    this.documentService.downloadFolder(this.folderId!).subscribe(res => saveAs(res, this.folderName + '.zip'));
  }
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly ziping with angular or downloading files?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo both of them. may be the way I choose not correct so the result of download zip file failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this just move zip file into back-end and send response that zip file to front-end save it.

```
    public StreamingResponseBody downloadFolder(String id) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Drive drive = getService();
        List<File> files = getAllFilesInFolder(id);

        StreamingResponseBody stream = output -> {
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(output);
            files.forEach(file -> {
                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    drive.files().get(file.getId()).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(baos);
                    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
                    zos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    zos.closeEntry();
                    baos.flush();
                    baos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error when download file in folder ", e);
                }
            });
            zos.finish();
            zos.close();
        };

        return stream;
    }
```